# Meaning of "the range of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $\ln{x}\cdot(3x^2-2(a+3)x+3a) \le 0$ is $0 < x \le b$, when $a>1$, $b>1$"?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, logarithms

This is the part of the problem I was solving, but I am stuck in interpreting the condition written in the title.

In the process, I got $f(x) = (x-3)(x-a)$, and $g(x) = f(x) + \left\{ (f(x)+xf'(x) \right\} \ln{x}$.

And to use the condition:

> - the range of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $g(x) \le f(x)$ is $0 < x \le b$
> - $a>1, b>1$

I rearranged the equation in the form of $g(x)-f(x)$ and did some calculation, and the condition becomes just like the title :

> - the range of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $\ln{x}\cdot(3x^2-2(a+3)x+3a) \le 0$ is $0 < x \le b$, when $a>1$, $b>1$

My idea was observing 4 ranges,

- $0<x<1$
- $x=1$
- $1<x\le b$
- $x > b$

Since the changes in $\ln{x}$ were obvious, and all I can do is determining the signs of $3x^2-2(a+3)x+3a$ in those four areas.

But I can't come up with any thoughts of what to do next. The solution says $a=3$ can be derived from this condition, but I don't see how.

---

**+edit:**

In those four ranges, signs of $\ln{x}$ becomes $(-) \to 0 \to (+) \to (+)$. So to meet the condition, quadratic function must be $(+)\to 0\to0\to(+)$.
Thus, $f(x) = 3(x-1)(x-b)$, making $a=3$.

I don't think this approach is rigorous at all, but this is my solution.

Comment: How about: Since $h(x) := 3x^2-2(a+3)x+3a \ge 0$ for all $0 < x < 1$, we have $h(1) \ge 0$ i.e. $a \ge 3$. Since $h(x) \le 0$ for all $1 < x \le b$, we have $h(1) \le 0$ i.e. $a \le 3$. Thus, $a = 3$.